# variables for saving a file in folder

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I want to save the created file in the folder how can i do so?
This is my view code:

```
day = 'monday'
score = 45
name = f'Alicia {score} in {day}'
file_name = "%s.xlsx" % name
df.to_excel(file_name, index=False)
```

I want to save under a new folder with the name Alicia.

Expected output:

The newFolder =  to the variable name without {Score} and {day}

```
Alicia/Alicia 45 in monday.xlsx
Peter/ Peter 67 in Tuesday.xlsx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
import os

name = "Alicia"
try:
    os.mkdir(f'./{name}')
except OSError as e:
    print("Directory exists")


day = 'monday'
score = 45
name = f'{name}/{name} {score} in {day}'
file_name = "%s.xlsx" % name
df.to_excel(file_name, index=False)
```

Comment: I edited my question, it was my mistake. The folder name will depends of the variable `name` without puting the day and score

Comment: @Pythonista, I edit the code block, is this your answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new folder by using the `os` module:

```
folderpath = <your_folder_path>       # path to new folder, e.g. /home/user/project/AI
if not os.path.exists(folderpath): 
    os.mkdir(folderpath)              # create new folder
```

You can then use that folder to save your file there:

```
file_path = os.path.join(folderpath, file_name)
df.to_excel(file_path, index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os` module of python which is built in in python
Use:
`dirname = str(os.makedirs("Folder Name")) f = open(f"{dirname}//yourfile", "w") f.write("Hello") f.close()`

This will create a file in Folder Name folder